# Changing Solidity tags from Solidity-0.5.0 to Solidity-0.5.x

Tags: discussion, tagging

There are two tags right now that should be changed. [solidity-0.5.0](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidity-0.5.0) and [solidity-0.6.0](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidity-0.6.0) by definition refer to a very specific subversion of Solidity (0.5.0 and 0.6.0, respectively), however these tags are used for *all* subversions of the specific version (e.g., people will use [solidity-0.5.0](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidity-0.5.0) for questions pertaining to version 0.5.1 of Solidity).

Can we change these tags to read [solidity-0.5.x](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidity-0.5.x) and [solidity-0.6.x](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidity-0.6.x), similar to how the web3js tag is [web3js-v1.x](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web3js-v1.x).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for raising this and the helpful suggestion: both tags have been updated.

In case people were interested, this is one output from moderator tool:

> Preview tag rename Be careful! There is no revision history generated
>   by this action!
>
> Remember that caching of question lists may make it look like the tag
>   still exists after the merge, but it doesn't!
>
> solidity-0.5.0 will be removed from 89 questions
>
> solidity-0.5.x will be added to 89 questions
>
> (These counts include deleted questions and exclude overlapping tags.)

Comment: Thank you for updating them!